# Link to login to social Media from app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

In my app I want to have a link or button that can use stored credentials to login to social media sites - say facebook.  But, since I plan on having a multiple links/buttons to different sites that may use different login info, I cannot force users to login to my app using any of the social media credentials.

Please forget the storing of credentials for now - that is a different issue altogether.

My question is Can I send the user's info to Facebook to allow them to login without having to take them to the login screen?  If so, where to best find the information to do that?

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I am a noob to app dev and still trying to get my direction.  Any sites or links with information would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If your user has previously authenticated to Facebook, you will have a Token, and there is no need to send the user to the login screen each time the user starts your app. Again, you need to be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the answer but from my experience you need to go through Facebook API to log in an android application using facebook,same for other social network. No clue what you wanted to do use a HTTP POST with the credential ?

There is a serious security issue with what you're trying to do, because it's you're application that handles the social network credential and so you would need to encrypt them store them and so on...

So if you want to give a try to Facebook Android API it's here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with the `Facebook` API is too much easy. You will follow some steps to import it into your project. Register your App on facebook developer site. Put the facebook `button` into your `layout`.

When the user clicks on the button the `API` will handle all the subsequent steps starting from taking the user `username` and `password` and will reply to you with a temporary `accessToken` that will be valid for two months. **This is the only communication way with Facebook API**, if you want to give the Facebook API any info with any other way. I am sorry to tell you you will not be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks.  Here is a followup.  Will the API allow me to connect the user to the Mobile App or the Mobile version of the Site?  Or either?

Comment: It will allow you to retrieve all the possible information that the Facebook knows about the user like, name, friends, likes, friends,  profile picture ... etc